# Prevent SQL injection with Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria, nhibernate-hql

I'm going through Hibernate and I know that you can prevent SQL injection with HQL:

```
String query1 = "from Obj where id = "+ id;
String query2 = "from Obj where id = :id";
```

`query1` is unsafe while `query2` is safe.

How can I achieve safe queries with Criteria? Is this already implemented or do I have to do something else?

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Obj.class);
c.add(Restrictions.eq("id", 5));
```

Comment: SQL injection can be prevented in Java by using `PreparedStatement`s and parameterized queries as `PreparedStatement` escapes unsafe characters, rendering an injection attack harmless.  Parameterized and criteria queries with Hibernate use `PreparedStatement`s so you get SQL injection protection out-of-the-box.  The only time you are not safe is when you try to hand-code queries like in your first example.

Comment: in my example number 5 can be unsafe. If I get 5 from post, what do I need to do, to exclude for example ´5 and 1 = 1´

Comment: This will get escaped automatically, no need to worry.  To convince yourself, run a test and make sure that you do not get unexpected results.

Comment: I have added a [test case](https://github.com/manish-in-java/spring-jpa-hibernate/blob/master/src/test/java/org/example/data/inventory/StockRepositoryTest.java) (`testSQLInjection` method) to a sample app of mine to check protection against SQL Injection attacks. If SQL Injection had worked, this test would fail because the second query that uses malicious input would have returned all rows from the affected database table. The fact that the test passes proves that the second query returned zero results, which is expected if the input was correctly escaped before being sent to the database.

Comment: thank you. Will run it. :). Why dont you post your code bellow so I can accept answer.

Answer (score 5):

> I'm going through Hibernate and I know that you can prevent SQL injection with HQL:

It is a very common misconception that ORM solutions, like hibernate, are SQL Injection proof. Hibernate allows the use of "native SQL" and defines a proprietary query language, named, HQL (Hibernate Query Language); the former is prone to SQL Injection and the later is prone to HQL (or ORM) injection.
Source: http://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/fix-sql-injection-in-java-hibernate

> How can I achieve safe queries with Criteria?

As far as your latter question is concerned, Criteria API (similar to PreparedStatement) escapes the parameters and won't cause malicious SQL to be executed.

The bottom line is don't concatenate your application's parameters directly into your query (and make use of Criteria, PreparedStatement), your app is safe.

Comment: >"Criteria API (similar to PreparedStatement) escapes the parameters"
How?

Answer (score 1):

A note about SQL injection:

Since it is the hot topic, I will address it now but discuss in detail later.
Hibernate does not grant immunity to SQL Injection, one can misuse the api as they please.
There is nothing special about HQL (Hibernates subset of SQL) that makes it any more or less susceptible.

Functions such as createQuery(String query) and createSQLQuery(String query) create a Query object that will be executed when the call to commit() is made. If the query string is tainted you have sql injection. The details of these functions are covered later.

Ref: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Hibernate