# HQL injection with Postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql, hql, sql-injection

I'm trying to understand how HQL injections work but I need help.
I send my server an HTTP POST request with the following json :

```
{
    "status":"COMMUNICATION",
    "planning": {
    "from": "01-20-2013",
    "to": "11-12-2015"
    }
}
```

I know that it is possible to inject a fraudulent request at the end of the **"status"** parameter because when I close with a simple quote (like this : `"status":"COMMUNICATION'"`) the server returns a Hibernate error with the request :

```
{
    "exception": "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException", 
    "error": "Internal Server Error", 
    "message": "org.hibernate.QueryException: expecting ''', found '<EOF>' [SELECT com FROM com.company.CorRequest as com where com.corCommunicationId > 0 AND com.status = 'COMMUNICATION'' AND com.scheduledDate > to_timestamp('01-20-2013','MM-dd-yyyy HH24:MI') AND com.scheduledDate <= to_timestamp('11-12-2015','MM-dd-yyyy HH24:MI')]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: expecting ''', found '<EOF>' [SELECT com FROM com as com where com.corCommunicationId > 0 AND com.status = 'COMMUNICATION'' AND com.scheduledDate > to_timestamp('01-20-2013','MM-dd-yyyy HH24:MI') AND com.scheduledDate <= to_timestamp('11-12-2015','MM-dd-yyyy HH24:MI')]", 
    "path": "/v1/comuni/", 
    "timestamp": 1579167902428, 
    "status": 500
}
```

When I inject `"COMMUNICATION')--"` I get the **entire** table back but I can't do anything else, do you have any ideas?

Comment: Are you thinking about how to handle this on server side or how to prevent bad requests on the client side?

Comment: How to handle this on server side because I want to try to do a POC with database extraction.

Comment: I suggest you look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31314209/prevent-sql-injection-with-hibernate - You will find a link in there to https://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/ .  Although not tackling Postgres on that site - the same principles should apply.

Comment: I have indeed come across these resources but I can't get out of the context of the table, a demo with SQLMAP exists ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6WeUxAmYgHQ) but I don't know why it doesn't work when I launch my attack.

Answer (score 2):

Injections always follow the same path of attack. Let's see the basics.

1. Submit malicious data to the service
2. The service puts this data into some structure (XML, HTML, SQL, LDAP query, shell command, etc...)
3. If the service is vulnerable, you can break out of the data scope and modify the structure itself, giving you XML/HTML/SQL/LDAP/command, etc. injection

For great [overview of injections, read this post](https://www.securitydrops.com/injections/).

Looking at your example, here is what's happening.

1. You submit `COMMUNICATION)'--` as a malicious input
2. Your service, using HQL, creates an SQL query like the following: `SELECT com FROM com.company.CorRequest as com where com.corCommunicationId > 0 AND com.status = 'COMMUNICATION'--' AND ...`
3. You broke out of the data scope of `com.status` and were able to modify the structure of the query itself by commenting out everything after `com.status = COMMUNICATION`

This is why you get the entire table back.

So how do you extract data from different tables? Here are some techniques that [sqlmap supports](https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap/wiki/Techniques). The easiest is to use `UNION query-based` injection: submit `UNION ALL SELECT xy FROM different_table` as the malicious input, and you should be able to query `different_table` and extract data.

Now, of course, your setup is unique, and I have no idea about the code that's running around the query. It might happen that some application logic is hiding this flaw and making it harder / impossible to exploit. The example you provided should be POC enough to warrant a fix. I wrote a short post [about trusting incoming data](https://www.securitydrops.com/untrusted-data/) and the mindset you should have around it.

If you really would like to go as far as trying to extract data using sqlmap, I recommend taking a look at the documentation of the [arbitrary injection point feature](https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap/wiki/Usage#arbitrary-injection-point).

Guessing from the information you provided, the injection point would be something like this: `COMMUNICATION)'*`.